# How to change Balance type from u128 type to U256 in runtime?

Tags: runtime, data-type

In substrate runtime and in many frame pallets the type Balance/BalanceOf uses u128 type everywhere. How to change that type to U256 from primitive-types crate in runtime and all frame pallets and make that type as native currency in the runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is impossible.

Take a look at the `pallet_balances::Config::Balance`'s definition:

```rust
pub trait Config<I: 'static = ()>: Config {
    type Balance: Parameter + Member + AtLeast32BitUnsigned + Codec + Default + Copy + MaybeSerializeDeserialize + Debug + MaxEncodedLen + TypeInfo + FixedPointOperand;
    ..
}
```

`U256` must satisfy those traits bound.

AFAIK, `U256` doesn't implement `AtLeast32BitUnsigned`.

If you want to do that, you have to write your own `pallet-balances` or `primitives-types`.

---

Moonbeam is an Ethereum-like chain. But it also uses `u128` on the Substrate side. And use `U256` in EVM side.

Use `u128` and convert it to `U256`.

```rust
// u128 -> U256
let u_128: u128 = 0_u128;
let u_256: U256 = U256::from(u_128);

// U256 -> u128
let u_128: u128 = u_256.low_u128();


// ---

// u128 to Balance
use sp_runtime::traits::SaturatedConversion;
let balance: Balance = u_128.saturated_into::<Balance>();
```

Comment: This is possible. But my question is different. when I give Balance type in runtime as U256 directly instead of u128 I am facing lots of errors.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Understood. What would be the changes required in pallet_balances on high level?

Comment: Remove the traits bound that `U256` doesn't implement. But you will meet a lot of questions in the future.